# MySQL Query 2 Tables in 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem writing a MySQL query to get data from 2 tables in the same database. I don't know how to combine the 2 tables into 1 table basically so that I can use PHP to display the information. Right now I am using 2 queries and PHP to join them... I really need the persons name and the score they got.

```
tbl_scores
----------
user_id
points

tbl_users
---------
user_id
name
```

tbl_users has more fields but those are the only ones that matter I think? Please help or send what I need to look up to learn more.

Comment: This is a rudimentary  `JOIN` operation:  `SELECT tbl_scores.user_id, tbl_scores.points, tbl_users.name FROM tbl_users LEFT JOIN tbl_scores ON tbl_users.user_id = tbl_scores.user_id`

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on SQL Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_join) is pretty useful. I used `LEFT JOIN` in case a user has no rows in the scores table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking to use is JOIN... more information on MySQL JOINs can be found all over the internet but I found one here: http://mysqljoin.com/

The following code is untested but should work for your scenario...

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    s.points
FROM
    tbl_users AS u LEFT JOIN tbl_scores AS s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_scores RIGHT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_scores.user_id = tbl_users.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and more specificaly [Left Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) because it returns all rows from the left table (tbl_users ), even if there are no matches in the right table (tbl_scores) so that you get all users even those with no score :

```
   SELECT * FROM  tbl_users LEFT JOIN tbl_scores ON 
     tbl_users.user_id =  tbl_scores.user_id;
```

Comment: The direction of the join doesn't matter as long as it points to the table you want to have the mandatory data, hence why my right join works just as well as your left join.